# My mesh becomes messed up when I join different mesh. Why is this happening?

Tags: modeling, import

I am a beginner, started working on a model few weeks ago but i was using blender 2.8, when i came to know about an update, i quickly upgraded to 2.82a but my blend file got all weird after re importing.

When I separated the mesh in edit mode, by materials or by lose parts,mesh becomes normal again. I have linked the images as well as the blender file regarding the problem.

I have tried importing and exporting using fbx, obj etc. I also removed all of the shape keys but it also did not fix the problem. The file still opens and works fine in blender 2.8 though.
this issue is also happening with 2.81.
[image: This is after separating or before joining]

[image: This is after joining mesh(using ctrl J)]

Blend file
https://drive.google.com/open?id=1KNnAh_Hxqvh1U13GGNjy6QK5Zc_utLq_

Comment: There is only one mesh object in your file and it looks like on the first picture in 2.82.a. Don't you have any add-on enabled?

Comment: When I open the file, it's supposed to be broken?
Because it looks fine for me. I think you just need to switch to the latest stable (not a) and book this under "strange bug, happy it's fixed"

Comment: I actually looked into it and discussed in the community, it's opening properly on every other pc except mine, actually no file is opening on my pc on Blender 2.82a but everything works fine with 2.80