# Mirror + Subdivision Surface just breaks after i merge 2 objects

Tags: modeling, modifiers, subdivision-surface, mirror-modifier

Well.. I was just modeling and ran into a problem that I couldn’t find a solution to on the Internet.

I have one object for a body and one for a hand.
[image]

When i join them using Ctrl+J everything seems normal. Next i add mirror modifier.
[image]

But when i add subdivision suface everything looks so broken. (look at picture)
[image]

And when I switch between object mode and edit mode the bug looks different every time
[image]

*By the way, turning the palm normals out didn't help, although I would still do it in the future.*
[image]

**Source files (i hope it possible to download):**

- [Before I did anything](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1fy-X-XN73nbcGt2jw-5tG0O2qmfhuCIG/view?usp=drive_link)
- [After I did all the above](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1zmlZCXu4hMcVohmh8ACzp1y-_OPNSKxG/view?usp=drive_link) (*When I open it it looks like in the
  screenshots. Let's see what it looks like for you.*)

I will be grateful for your help (☞ﾟヮﾟ)☞

Comment: Hello could you please share your file?

Comment: Here. I've updated the post and added a link to the original file below.

Comment: That works fine here! The only thing I'd say is that when you join the hand to the body the normals on the hand part are inverted, but you can sort that by selecting All in Edit mode and using Shift-N to recalculate them. Please add a blend file which you took your images from so that we can see what's going on.

Comment: that's weird, I don't see any problem in the second file either, except you need to recalculate the normals because the hand faces are flipped

Comment: I think I've seen that here in the past... that was gpu issue (if I remember well). Which Blender version do you use?

Comment: I found one similar case on the forums.
https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/172470/my-mesh-becomes-messed-up-when-i-join-different-mesh-why-is-this-happening
And apparently there’s just something wrong with my blender.

Comment: I use version 3.1.2

Comment: Can you try a 3.6 LTS ?

Comment: I tried updating to 3.6 LTS and yes, that fixed everything.

Comment: It was fine in 3.3 LTS too so it was obviously your version causing the problem. You should find that recalculating the normals works fine too now that you've updated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Even though the normals of the palms were turned inside out after merging the objects, this was not the cause of the problem. The cause of the problem was my old version. I updated to 3.6 LTS and everything started working fine.

Thank you everyone 
[image]